# Проблема с ботом ВК

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Использую vk_api, longpoll, но:

- if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_EDIT: выполняется только если пишешь боту в лс, а не в группу.
- if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW: выполняется только если пишешь в общий чат.
- if event.type == VkBotEventType.PHOTO_NEW: не выполняется ни так, ни так.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Нужно только, чтобы всё отслеживалось в общем чате.

Вот мой код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='<--->')
vk = vk_session.get_api()

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '<--->')

keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
keyboard.add_button('Привет', color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)
keyboard.add_button('Клавиатура', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
keyboard.add_line()
keyboard.add_location_button()
keyboard.add_line()
keyboard.add_vkpay_button(hash="action=transfer-to-group&group_id=<--->")


for event in longpoll.listen():

    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.message["text"] == 'Hi':
            if event.from_chat:
                vk.messages.send(
                    key='<--->',
                    server='<--->',
                    ts='1',
                    random_id=get_random_id(),
                    message='Привет!',
                    chat_id=event.chat_id
                )

        if 'Keys' == event.message["text"]:
            if event.from_chat:
                vk.messages.send(
                    keyboard=keyboard.get_keyboard(),
                    key='<--->',
                    server='<--->',
                    ts='1',
                    random_id=get_random_id(),
                    message='Держи',
                    chat_id=event.chat_id
                )

    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_EDIT:
        if event.from_chat:
            print('edited')
```

Comment: А в чем то суть проблемы вообще???